# How can I store multiple "ship to contact" in Order?

Tags: order

I am trying to create an order management system. Accounts sign a contract with us which can include multiple orders. We ship data to select contacts within the account. I can see that Order has a "ship to contact" field, but I want to be able to ship to multiple contacts. Anyone achieved this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A "Ship to" is often considered as simply an address as opposed to a contact in many Order systems. The "Ship to" is then specified when the Order is placed. How to handle this greatly depends on your product and the type of customer you have.

I can think of the situation where you have a chain of stores and they want something shipped to Store Number 216 which has a unique address associated with it. In that situation, you'd probably want to have a custom contact object for that account with each of their store numbers and their addresses.

In other situations, you might have a reseller who's got an untold number of customers (yet to be determined) that you'll have to service and ship to. That reseller most likely doesn't know their names or addresses yet to even provide them to you. Trying to keep track of them along with the question of whether to even retain them might ultimately come down to deciding whether it's a good use of your company's resources.

If you have a situation where a company only has 2 or 3 alternate shipping addresses, then you may want to add alternate custom ship to fields to your your Account object. Again, that would primarily be for the convenience of your salesmen and customers, provided you had Ship To 1, 2 and 3, etc set up as options in your Order System (if using the Account's ShipTo Address). Alternatively, you could add them to Contacts as "related ShipTo contacts for Accounts" using a unique Contact Record Type then select which one to use at the time the order is placed.

None of us can really tell you what to do as we don't know your particular situation. Instead, we can only tell you there are countless ways of architecting a solution to this, all of which would depend on your particular situation and anticipated needs.

Comment: I am trying to model a subscription business. There are Accounts that subscribe to a particular product through putting in an Order. All Contacts within this Account are entitled to the product. I need to be able to query the Order object to see which contacts are entitled to the product. The products are newsletters and I am limited to the Professional Edition!

Comment: Contacts can be related to Accounts as children. But, according to [this help page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/dev_package_features_pe_ge.htm) PE doesn't support Record Types, so unless all of your Contacts for an Account will also be subscribers, I'd recommend using a separate object to hold the shipping addresses.

Comment: Thanks. In our use case, all Contacts are subscribers. If so, how would I run a report to determine which Contacts are subscribed to Products Ordered by an Account?

Comment: I think I just posted an answer to your question on that subject.